# 既にあるホームページに、新しく作ったフォルダーのホームページをデプロイする方法を知りたい。

Tags: git, デプロイ

既に「Nuxt＋Vuetify」で作成したホームページはgithub経由でNetlifyにデプロイしています。このフォルダーは「smalltrip」です（旧フォルダーとします）。リニューアルするために新しいフォルダーに「Nuxt＋Tailwind」で作成し直しました。このフォルダーは「smalltrip2023」です（新フォルダーとします）。git関係の根本をよく知らないまま、SourceTreeを使いホームページ更新できていましたが、今回、次の事をしたりして、収拾がつかなくなりました。

1. 旧フォルダー名を「smalltrip2022」とし、新フォルダーを「smalltrip」とした。
2. コンソールで `git push` したらエラーになった。
3. `git remote add origin <私のリモートリポジトリ>` でもエラーになった。
4. SourceTreeで「Add Commit Push」をやったがエラーになった。

質問は、私のように新しいフォルダーをデプロイする一般的なことをお知りの方、ご教授をお願いします。
また、できれば、収拾のつかなくなった私のケースを復旧する方法を教えてください。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ひとまず、それぞれ元のフォルダ名に戻せば元の状態に戻りませんか？

Comment: backupがあったので、git前の状態に戻りました。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。gitの勉強をしてやり方が分かりました。

次のサイトを参照しました。

[2. GitとGitHubを使ったチーム開発の超入門 | 【超入門】初心者のためのGitとGitHubの使い方](https://tech-blog.rakus.co.jp/entry/20200529/git#2-Git%E3%81%A8GitHub%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%83%81%E3%83%BC%E3%83%A0%E9%96%8B%E7%99%BA%E3%81%AE%E8%B6%85%E5%85%A5%E9%96%80)

まず、フォルダー名は関係なかった。
やったことの要約を示します。

- リポジトリをクローンする
- ブランチを作成する
- ブランチでコミットする
- リモートリポジトリにプッシュする
- コードレビュー・マージ

これでサイトのリニューアルが出来ました。